# radon transform with parallel computing

Tags: image, matlab, parallel-processing

here a code that performs the 2D reconstruction with Radon and iRadon transforms with parallel computing on matlab.
My problem is if the input image dimension is NxM, the output image is always Nx(Mxnumber of processors).
for eg if my input image is 256x256,and the number of processors used is 4, so  the output one is 256x(256x4): (256x1024)???
i really don't know what to do??

```
clc, clear, close all;
f=phantom(256); 
theta=0:179;
tic;
matlabpool(4) 
x=distributed(f); 
spmd 
wx=getLocalPart(x); 
g=radon(wx,theta); 
g=iradon(g,theta,1,256); 
end 
g = gather(g);
conctstrong text=[g{:}];
matlabpool close; 
toc;

subplot(2,1,1), 
imshow(conct);
title('Fileterd backprojection');

subplot(2,1,2), 
imshow(f);
title('Original image');
```

Answer (score 1):

With 4 workers you are gathering four n x m arrays which results in a n x (4*m) array because gather simply concatenates the matrices.